# Postgres function(via npgsql) call to ExecuteNonQuery returns -1 as result for rows affected

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I have a simple function that just inserts the parameter values provided to it into columns in a table.

When I run the function via the ExecuteNonQuery() method on the command object I always get -1, even if the insert took place.

If i run the same query as a Text command it gives be the correct result of 1.

I'm new to postgresql/npgsql. Is there trick to making the function feed back the number of rows affected? Something like "set nocount off" in SQL Server?

**EDIT:**
The code I am using: (with npgsql 2.0.11)

```
var connStr = @"Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=***;Database=Test;";
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connStr)) {
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert_something";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        NpgsqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters["_id"].Value = 1;
        cmd.Parameters["_val"].Value = 2;
        var rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(rowsAffected);
    }
}
```

Comment: [This work for me: "How to return the result of a postgresql function in c#? Console output empty"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31241309/2825284)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used Npgsql, but the documentation has an example with
the following code:

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into table1 values(1, 1)", conn);
Int32 rowsaffected;

try
{
    rowsaffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

If you are talking about some PostgreSQL function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myinsert(integer) RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'sql' AS 'INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ($1)';
```

and you are doing something like `SELECT myinsert(1);`, you can't get the number of affected rows, because you are running a SELECT and what the function does internally is opaque to you.

Answer (score 1):

For ExecuteNonQuery() to get the number of rows affected, your postgresql function should return just that. An example would be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_something(_id int, _val int)
RETURNS int as $$
DECLARE count int;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO some_table (id, value) VALUES(_id, _val);
    GET DIAGNOSTICS count = ROW_COUNT;
    RETURN count;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Now if you call ExecuteNonQuery() from your code, you should get the inserted rows count.

Comment: Should? What makes you say it "should"? Have you tried this, or do you know this from experience?

Comment: I have used (am using) similar functions. I didn't get to test this particular piece code, hence the "should."

Comment: I just tested this with npgsql 2.0.11. No luck. The result of ExecuteNonQuery is still -1. ;(

Comment: I'm going to check this out. Would you mind to fill a bug report about that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I have implemented and its working for me without any issues:

Add an `OUT` Parameter to your function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.UpdateSomeValue(
IN par_updateId text,
OUT par_returnvalue INT4)

BEGIN
    UPDATE schema.TableToUpdate
    SET status = 1 
    WHERE ID = par_updateId;
                
    GET DIAGNOSTICS par_returnvalue = ROW_COUNT;

END;
```

Now on the C# side

```
private int UpdateSomeValue()
{
    var connStr = @"Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;UserId=postgres;Password=***;Database=Test;";
    int result = -1;
    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connStr)) {
                conn.Open();
                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "shema.UpdateSomeValue";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("par_updateId",NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.INT, 1);
                    NpgsqlParameter outParm = new NpgsqlParameter("par_returnvalue", 
                    NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer)
                        {
                            Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                        };
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    result = Convert.ToInt32(outParm.Value);
                }
            }
      return result;    

}
```

PS : I tried the just `ExecuteNonQuery()` approach but it was always returning `-1` for me (as if no rows has been affected [NpgsqlDocumentation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.html))  Using above way I was able to capture the Number of rows affected from the PostgreSQL function and with `OUT` parameter it was easy to catch the affected rows on the client side.