# How to return the result of a postgresql function in c#? Console output empty

Tags: c#, postgresql, plpgsql

I have the problem that i have a function in postgresql that calculates two integer and should return the result to the c# (npgsql) conosle and i don't know where my mistake is, because the debugger doesn't say anything to me which is helpful.

so first of all the code of c# and of the function.

```
                ...
            cmd.Parameters["x"].Value = 20;
            cmd.Parameters["y"].Value = 22;
            connection.Open();

            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) {
                //Console.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters["x"].Value);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters["sum"].Value);

            }
```

and now the code of the DB:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t2(
    IN x integer,
    IN y integer,
    OUT sum integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$BEGIN
    sum := x + y;
    INSERT INTO  t2 (x, y, sum) values (x, y, sum);
END
```

So when i try to run it,

```
Console.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters["sum"].Value);
```

will be empty and the ["sum"].Value is NULL. What am I doing wrong? Am I right, that when I say that "sum" is an OUT variable, I do not need a return?

Please help.

**SOLVED, thank you to all! @Patrick gave me the right answer:**
use ExecuteScalar() instead of ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Are you actually executing the command? I can't see that in your code...

Comment: with command do you mean the function?
yes i do, but i think that is not the problem?
`DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
               command.CommandText = "t2";
                command.CommandType = 
CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Comment: edited full code now ;)

Comment: I mean your "command" object. You need to run one of the  methods starting with "execute" (sorry, can't remember which one off-hand) after opening the connection; that's the bit that actually runs the query on the database...

Comment: oh you mean `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`? Just added it, tried it alrdy , but it didn't work either.

Comment: Check your variable names - you appear to be mixing up "command" and "cmd"...

Comment: yes true, thank you.
but primary failure was use ExecuteScalar() instead of ExecuteNonQuery(). it is solved now. thank you mlinth anyway. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

you should call

```
Object res = command.ExecuteScalar();
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Comment: Hi Patrick,
doesn't work for me. `Console.WriteLine(command.Parameters["sum"].Value);` stays empty.

Comment: `ExecuteScalar()` returns the result of the function call. You should not look at the parameter here, but at the result of the call.

Comment: I am not entirely sure about this, but Npgsql may not support the use of PG `OUT` parameters. In PG, a declared `OUT` parameter is just a notational variation of the `RETURNS` clause.

Comment: ok, well thats true, i have to look at the result.
thank you, thats working.

so the failure was **use ExecuteScalar() instead of ExecuteNonQuery()**.

THANKS!

Comment: Since I am new, how do i do that? Just clicked the hook?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run this code, for example, [command.ExecuteNonQuery()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ? Because you're reading a value without actually executing the query.

```
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
int result = (int) cmd.Parameters["sum"].Value;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Hi Alex,
sorry I just took the wrong code, because I tried and tried and disabled the ExecuteNonQuery(); I had it.
When i tried your code, i get an NullReferenceException with `int result = (int)command.Parameters["sum"].Value;`

Comment: Thank you Alex. Patrick solved it, it was ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery.

Anyway, thank you. ;)

Comment: I thinked about it, but removed ExecuteScallar code because it doesn't work always with output parameters :) It's good that your data provider support this feature. But do not very count on it