# PostgreSql : how can we call stored procedures inout parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, postgresql, function, stored-procedures, npgsql

I can take data from functions but I can not call stored procedures parameters in C# with Npgsql. Do you have an idea?

Comment: [This work for me: "How to return the result of a postgresql function in c#? Console output empty"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31241309/2825284)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example:

```cs
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT my_func()", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("p_out", DbType.String) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters[0].Value);
}
```

For more information, take a look at [the documentation](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#stored-functions-and-procedures).

Comment: Your PostgreSQL function needs to have an output parameter (read [the PG docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) or find a tutorial on how to write such a function). Then, on the Npgsql client side, the code snippet above will load the function's parameter (named `p_out` in this example) into the parameter. You can then access it as in the code sample to get the value out.